# Unformat formatted String

Tags: java, string, format, printf, string-formatting

I have a simple formatted String:

```
double d = 12.348678;
int i = 9876;
String s = "ABCD";
System.out.printf("%08.2f%5s%09d", d, s, i);

// %08.2f = '12.348678' -> '00012,35'
// %5s = 'ABCD' -> ' ABCD'
// %09d = '9876' -> '000009876'
// %08.2f%5s%09d = '00012,35 ABCD000009876'
```

When i know the pattern: `%08.2f%5s%09d` and String: `00012,35 ABCD000009876`:
Can i "unformat" this String in some way?

eg. the expected result something like 3 tokens: '00012,35', ' ABCD', '000009876'

Comment: May I ask what is the problem you want to solve with unformatting?

Comment: I want to compare some values in automated tests. I know only pattern and output.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to your pattern. A general parser for a formatstring, (because what we call unformatting is parsing) would look much different.

```
public class Unformat {

    public static Integer getWidth(Pattern pattern, String format) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(format);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getResult(Pattern p, String format, String formatted,
            Integer start, Integer width) {
        width = getWidth(p, format);
        if (width != null) {
            String result = formatted.substring(start, start + width);
            start += width;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String format = "%08.2f%5s%09d";
        String formatted = "00012.35 ABCD000009876";
        String[] formats = format.split("%");

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Integer start = 0;
        Integer width = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j < formats.length; j++) {
            if (formats[j].endsWith("f")) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*([0-9])+\\..*f");
                result.add(getResult(p, formats[j], formatted, start, width));
            } else if (formats[j].endsWith("s")) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9])s");
                result.add(getResult(p, formats[j], formatted, start, width));
            } else if (formats[j].endsWith("d")) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9])d");
                result.add(getResult(p, formats[j], formatted, start, width));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: What would happen if the format exceeds the width of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your output format of `"%08.2f%5s%09d"`, it seems comparable to this pattern

`"([0-9]{5,}[\\.|,][0-9]{2,})(.{5,})([0-9]{9,})"`

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "00012,35 ABCD000009876";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{5,}[\\.|,][0-9]{2,})(.{5,})([0-9]{9,})").matcher(data);

    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            matches.add(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Results:

```
[00012,35,  ABCD, 000009876]
```

### UPDATE

After seeing the comments, here's a generic example without using `RegularExpressions` as to not copy @bpgergo (+1 to you with generic `RegularExpressions` approach).  Also added some logic in case the format ever exceeded the width of the data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "00012,35 ABCD000009876";
    // Format exceeds width of data
    String format = "%08.2f%5s%09d%9s";
    String[] formatPieces = format.replaceFirst("^%", "").split("%");

    List<String> matches = new ArrayList();

    int index = 0;
    for (String formatPiece : formatPieces) {   
        // Remove any argument indexes or flags 
        formatPiece = formatPiece.replaceAll("^([0-9]+\\$)|[\\+|-|,|<]", "");

        int length = 0;
        switch (formatPiece.charAt(formatPiece.length() - 1)) {
            case 'f':
                if (formatPiece.contains(".")) {
                    length = Integer.parseInt(formatPiece.split("\\.")[0]);
                } else {
                    length = Integer.parseInt(formatPiece.substring(0, formatPiece.length() - 1));
                }
                break;
            case 's':
                length = Integer.parseInt(formatPiece.substring(0, formatPiece.length() - 1));
                break;
            case 'd':
                length = Integer.parseInt(formatPiece.substring(0, formatPiece.length() - 1));
                break;
        }

        if (index + length < data.length()) {                
            matches.add(data.substring(index, index + length));
        } else {
            // We've reached the end of the data and need to break from the loop
            matches.add(data.substring(index));
            break;
        }
        index += length;
    }
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Results:

```
[00012,35,  ABCD, 000009876]
```

Comment: this approach however is tailored for the exact order of segments. If a second string with `%09d%08.2f%5s` would come by, you would also need to create the corresponding regex entry therefore. Although this approach is much shorter then any other posted here, @bpgergo's approach is therefore a bit more flexible

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
//Find the end of the first value, 
//this value will always have 2 digits after the decimal point.
int index = val.indexOf(".") + 3;
String tooken1 = val.substring(0, index);

//Remove the first value from the original String
val = val.substring(index);

//get all values after the last non-numerical character.
String tooken3 = val.replaceAll(".+\\D", "");

//remove the previously extracted value from the remainder of the original String.
String tooken2 = val.replace(tooken3, "");
```

This will fail if the String value contains a number at the end and probably in some other cases.

Comment: The Problem is that i have more complicated output (almost always different length etc.). That was a simple example. I see that there is no simple way to solve this case and dedicated solution must be implemented. Thanks for proposal.

Comment: @akfmb This approach will work as long as the format is the same, it doesn't matter if any of the values is bigger then the minimum width specified in the format.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the pattern, it means that you are dealing with some kind of regular expression. Use them to utilize your needs.

Java has decent regular expression API for such tasks

Regular expressions can have capturing groups and each group would have a single "unformatted" part just as you want. All depends on regex you will use/create.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest thing to do would be to parse the string using a regex with myString.replaceAll(). myString.split(",") may also be helpful for splitting your string into a string array